# How I can add pushpins with name and description to bing maps

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

I creating app for windows phone 7 (bing maps) , and I need add something like this:

- when I tap on the map, I want add pushpin there, but I also need to add some information to that pushpin (like name and description)

how can i do this? or where can i find some tutorial for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the Tap event of the map and add Pushpins.

XAML:

```
<Maps:Map x:Name="Map" CredentialsProvider="Your-Creds" Tap="Map_OnTap" />
```

Code:

```
private void Map_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    GeoCoordinate location;
    if (Map.TryViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(Map), out location))
    {
        Map.Children.Add(new Pushpin
            {
                Location = location,
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                Content = "Hello world"
            });
    }
}
```

If you would like an MVVM approach you could have a collection of objects that you add to.

Xaml:

```
<Maps:Map x:Name="Map" CredentialsProvider="Your-creds" 
            Tap="Map_OnTap">
    <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                </Maps:Pushpin>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:Map>
```

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<MapLocation> Locations { get; private set; }

private void Map_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    GeoCoordinate location;
    if (Map.TryViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(Map), out location))
    {
        Locations.Add(new MapLocation
            {
                Location = location,
                Name = "Hello world"
            });
    }
}

public class MapLocation
{
    public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This example simply sets the DataContext of the page to be itself. A better approach is to set the DataContext of the page to be a view model with the Locations property on it.

Comment: yes, it's work, but "Tap" works always, whenever i touch the zoom buttons or tap on pushpin it's adding a new pushpin

Comment: You can add an event handler to the Pushpin [Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.UIElement.Tap);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Silverlight,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) event and set the [Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.gestureeventargs.handled(v=vs.105).aspx) property to true